# How to change Object Type in JavaParser

Tags: javaparser

I'm using JavaParser.

For example, I'm having below method

```
void checkCall()
{
    Blabla.test();
}
```

`Blabla.test();` is a static call. I want to change `Blabla.test()` to `ABCD.test()` without changing any other. I got Blabla from `methodCall.getScope().get()`. But how to use `methodCall.setScope()`? It's expecting Expression as a parameter.

Answer (score 1):

To understand what is going on you have to consider that *JavaParser* is a *parser*. So it means that it builds an Abstract Syntax Tree, it does not resolve symbols (this is done by JavaSymbolSolver). Therefore the scope here is not a class, from the point of view of JavaParser. It is instead a *name*, that someone later will resolve and figure out is a class.

All of this to say that you should use a *NameExpr* as your scope to be passed to *setScope*.

Source: I am a contributor to *JavaParser*